# Firebase Auth responds with _getRecaptchaConfig is not a function during signIn with Email and password

Tags: node.js, firebase, authentication

This is my API that logs the user In with Email and Password with Firebase. However, when I tried testing out this API I got an error that I'm somehow not able to fix and don't know where the error is persistent. I will be really thankful for your help.

The error:

> {"e": "TypeError: auth._getRecaptchaConfig is not a function"}

It is a JSON response from API.

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth, signInWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  authDomain: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  projectId: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  storageBucket: "XXXXXXXXXXXX",
  messagingSenderId: "XXXXXXXXXXX",
  appId: "XXXXXXXXX",
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export default async function handler(req, res) {
  if (req.method === "GET") {
    return res.send("Working");
  } else if (req.method === "POST") {
    const email = req.body.email;
    const password = req.body.password;
    const auth = getAuth();
    signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then((user) => {
        return res.status(200).json({ user });
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        return res.status(500).json({ e: `${e}` });
      });
  }
}
```

Comment: Ohh ok, apparently I'm a fool... I forgot to pass the auth instance... :(

Comment: I am a fool too

Comment: To provide more information for those who encounter this. Pass `auth` into the signInWithEmailAndPassword method when using the modular API version.

`import { getAuth, signInWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth";
const auth = getAuth();
signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)`

Answer (score 3):

I found this this question while experiencing the same error message myself, and I want to provide some additional info in case it is helpful to anyone else who stumbles into the same issue in the future as well.

The OP is correct in their comment that the root cause of the error is from not passing the auth instance into signInWithEmailAndPassword.

But there is an additional complication that can lead to this, which is what happened in my situation. If you are writing a 2nd generation Cloud Function that uses both Firebase Auth and Firestore, or if you are performing multiple different actions with Firebase Auth, you may need to import both firebase/auth package and the firebase-admin package.

For example, in my case I was importing createUserWithEmailAndPassword (similar to signInWithEmailAndPassword) from firebase/auth. But I also imported createCustomToken from firebase-admin so I could create a token to utilize with signing the user in after creating their account. createCustomToken is an auth function but is only available in firebase-admin, not firebase/auth. I also imported firebase-admin/firestore so I could use Firestore in the same function that uses Auth.

If you do this, you have to initialize the Firebase app with both the firebase package and the firebase-admin package. I did not know this, and I was initializing the app with firebase-admin and creating the auth instance, then passing the auth instance to createUserWithEmailAndPassword. This generated the `_getRecaptchaConfig is not a function` error. I was confused at first because I was passing the auth instance as required, but later I figured out the error was because I was not passing the *correct* auth instance for the package I was using.

As of the time this was written (June 2023), the Firebase docs don’t explain the difference clearly and inadvertently lead you into creating this problem because the [Firestore examples](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started?gen=2nd) show using firebase-admin for Firestore but the [Firebase Auth modular examples](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start#web-modular-api) show using firebase/auth. If you put both together, you may run into this same error, and the docs don’t warn you about it or explain how to fix it.

Here is an example of how to use both simultaneously (it is clunky but functional):

```
// @firebase package
const { initializeApp } = require("@firebase/app");
const { getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword } = require("@firebase/auth");

// firebase-admin package
const { initializeApp: initializeAdminApp } = require('firebase-admin/app');
const { getAuth: getAdminAuth, createCustomToken } = require('firebase-admin/auth');
const { getFirestore } = require('firebase-admin/firestore');

// Initialize firebase-admin
const adminApp = initializeAdminApp();
const adminAuth = getAdminAuth();
const firestore = getFirestore();

// Initialize @firebase
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "xxxxx",
  authDomain: "xxxxx",
  databaseURL: "xxxxx",
  projectId: "xxxxx",
  appId: "xxxxx",
};

const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const firebaseAuth = getAuth(firebaseApp);


// Example function
exports.createUserAndSignInWithToken = onCall({cors: true}, async (request) => {

  var result = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(firebaseAuth, 'test@abc.com', 'password').then(async function(userCredential) {

    var customToken = await adminAuth.createCustomToken(userCredential.user.uid);
    return customToken;

  });
  return result;

});
```

In the above example, firebaseAuth (created with firebase/auth) is used for createUserWithEmailAndPassword (and would also be used for signInWithEmailAndPassword) but adminAuth (created with firebase-admin) is used for createCustomToken.

This code successfully resolved the `_getRecaptchaConfig is not a function` error for me.