# Firebase: How do I deal with 'TypeError: authInternal._getRecaptchaConfig is not a function' when calling createUserWithEmailAndPassword

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, recaptcha

Like the title says. Im getting some kind of reCaptcha related error when trying to create a user. This is my first time using firebase so i might just be making a silly mistake.

This is the code that calls createUserWithEmailAndPassword

```
const signupUser = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setLoading(true);
    try {
      const userCredential = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        auth,
        email,
        password
      );
      // Signed in
      const user = userCredential.user;
      console.log(user);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
```

This is my firebase config

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import {getAuth} from "firebase/auth"

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "XXX",
  authDomain: "XXX",
  projectId: "XXX",
  storageBucket: "XXX",
  messagingSenderId: "XXX",
  appId: "XXX"
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export const auth = getAuth(app)
export default app
```

I have tried deleting node_modules and package-lock.json. I have also tried different browsers but still getting the same error.

Comment: Trying to find an answer to the same question. Came across this. Not sure how to use it myself in my app but nevertheless it might make more sense to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76135179/firebase-auth-responds-with-getrecaptchaconfig-is-not-a-function-during-signin